# How do I print out string values stored in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

I am using Java on NetBeans 8.  I have searched google and other stack overflow questions but I cannot find anything that relates to my question.  Also, I have consulted the oracle documentation and their example gave me the same error I am experiencing.

I would like the array string values below to print out to the output box using a line of code like:

```
        System.out.println(pbArray[0][0] + pbArray[1][0]);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

But no matter where I try to input that line of code I cannot make it work.  NetBeans tells me there is "an identifier expected."

```
package com.mnlottery.console;

public class ComMnlotteryConsole {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     class powerball{

     String[][] pbArray = {
        {"August 16th, 2014","August 13th, 2014","August 9th, 2014"},
        {"07, 08, 17, 48, 69, 09, $50,000,000","08, 37, 39, 40, 52, 24,"
                + " $40,000,000","03, 12, 31, 34, 51, 24, 90,000,000"}};
    }                     
}
}
```

I feel like this should be fairly simple.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you create `class powerball` inside `main` method of `ComMnlotteryConsole` class?

Comment: Where is `names` defined?

Comment: How use Arrays.toString?

Comment: @Pshemo Beause if I did not create that class, netbeans was telling me that pbArray was an un-used variable.  After I created that class within the main method pbArray turned green.

Comment: @DavidHouse So you fix problem you don't understand in a way you don't understand either. You probably should start reading Java tutorial ([official one is nice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)) of book.

Comment: I am foolish!  Did not realize inner class was not necessary.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted (no inner `class`)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] pbArray = {
            { "August 16th, 2014", "August 13th, 2014", "August 9th, 2014" },
            { "07, 08, 17, 48, 69, 09, $50,000,000",
                    "08, 37, 39, 40, 52, 24," + " $40,000,000",
                    "03, 12, 31, 34, 51, 24, 90,000,000" } };
    System.out.println(pbArray[0][0] + pbArray[1][0]);
}
```

But, you can print the array(s) in a few ways,

1. [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29)
2. A loop, and [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29)

like

```
String[][] pbArray = {
        { "August 16th, 2014", "August 13th, 2014", "August 9th, 2014" },
        { "07, 08, 17, 48, 69, 09, $50,000,000",
                "08, 37, 39, 40, 52, 24," + " $40,000,000",
                "03, 12, 31, 34, 51, 24, 90,000,000" } };
// 1.
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(pbArray));
// or 2.
for (String [] arr : pbArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Don't forget to use import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Helped me out quite a bit!  Didn't realize inner class was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Change `System.out.println(pbarray[0][0] + names[1][0]);` to

```
System.out.println(pbArray[0][0] + pbArray[1][0]);
```

names and pbarray do not exist. pbArray is the correct identifier.